# Set height of div to 100% of remaining space under header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs:

1. A header div at the top of the page with a set height of 150px.
2. A container div sitting under the header div.

What I would like is for the container div to be dynamic and resize to 100% of the remaining space underneath the header div.

I have tried putting in `height: 100%` but this makes the page need to scroll. I presume it is making the div 100% of the browser height rather than 100% of the remaining body's height.

How can I make it so that the container div simply resizes its height to the remaining body space?

Please find the relevant code below:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
#container {
  width: 760px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply do that by using some math with the [`calc()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Subtract 150px (the header size) from 100%. This is dynamically calculated.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
#container {
  width: 760px;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Compatibility:** `calc()` is supported in [most modern browsers and IE 9 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2cutobr/1/) and snippet below:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
#container {
  width: 760px;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that browser support for this is not fantastic. I would be especially concerned about lack of support in Android before 4.4. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @SteveSanders Worth noting thanks, also I've bookmarked this site, looks very useful and interesting indeed.

Comment: @Tom - You can cover for non supported browsers by providing an un-optimised height *above* the calc height. Something like `height: 90%; height: calc(100% - 150px);` This way non supporting browsers will gracefully degrade with a tad too much whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct modern way to acomplish this without css hacks is with **FlexBox**, which as of the writting of this post is supported by all modern browsers. [(**you can check browser compatibility here**)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

It also gives you more flexibility. If you later decide to add new rows (or even side columns) is very easy to acomplish without any calculations.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex; /* Activates FlexBox Model */
  flex-direction: column; /* Divs are spanned vertically */
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
}
#content {
  background-color: #888;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">My header with some stuff</div>
  <div id="content">My content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 - though there is no need for the 100% width or height on the container or html,body. Just place `min-height: 100vh` on the container and it will resize nicely with content. Might as well go all in with modern lengths when using modern CSS properties :)

Comment: @misterManSam yes indeed. And support for viewport units is just marginally worse than for FlexBox. All modern browsers (besides IE, ofc, lol) support it fully.

Answer (score 2):

The outer container has to have `position: relative` and the div that you want to stretch to the bottom has to have `position: absolute`. This solution is pure css with no calls to calc().

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #999999;
}

#mainContent {
    width: 760px;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wt0k73bz/**